# I want empty search returns to home page in my wordpress

Tags: search

I want empty search returns  to home page in my wordpress  . how i can do this . im trying to using javascript and html tags , but te are not too fast . if no result user returns  to home page not to nothing found page.

Comment: Like [this](http://wpengineer.com/2162/fix-empty-searches/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do exactly what you're asking for:

```
add_action('wp', 'redirect_empty_search');
function redirect_empty_search() {
  global $wp_query;
  if( isset( $_REQUEST['s'] ) && 0 === $wp_query->post_count ) {
    wp_redirect( home_url() );
    exit;
  }
}
```

You'll want to add some kind of message on the homepage when this happens, maybe by adding a query parameter to home_url() and displaying a message in your theme when that parameter is set. Something like:

```
wp_redirect( add_query_arg( 'searchfailed', '1', home_url() ) );
```

Comment: I was in the process of considering to suggest the same approach, but of course that isn't using javascript - and you just have been faster. I'd do it a little bit different, having the if condition like this: `isset($_GET['s']) && $_GET['s']==''` - no need for the global this way.

Comment: You know...I wonder if we hit a language barrier here. Your way is definitely much better for detecting empty searches (i.e. nothing in the search box). Mine is for empty search *results*.

Some clarification from the original poster would be really helpful. I think between the two of us, we have the perfect answer all ready to go.

Comment: You might be right about the language barrier. And you additional explanation is right on spot. I should have thought of writting that.. :D

Comment: @DaveRoss exactly what I wanted. Thanks a lot for your help.